# Kafka with multiple instances of microservices and end-users

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices

This is more of a design/architecture question.

1. We have a microservice A (MSA) with multiple instances (say 2) running of it behind LB.
2. The purpose of this microservice is to get the messages from Kafka topic and send to end users/clients. Both instances use same consumer group id for a particular client/user so as messages are not duplicated. And we have 2 (or =#instances) partitions of Kafka topic
3. End users/clients connect to LB to fetch the message from MSA. Long polling is used here.
4. Request from client can land to any instance. If it lands to MSA1, it will pull the data from kafka partion1 and if it lands to MSA2, it will pull the data from partition2.
5. Now, a producer is producing the messages, we dont have high messages count. So, lets say producer produce msg1 and it goes to partition1. End user/client will not get this message unless it's request lands to MSA1, which might not happen always as there are other requests coming to LB.
6. We want to solve this issue. We want that client gets the message near realtime.

One of the solution can be having a distributed persistent queue (e.g. ActiveMQ) where both MSA1 and MSA2 keep on putting the messages after reading from Kafka and client just fetch the message from queue. But this will cause separate queue for every end-user/client/groupid.
Is this a good solution, can we go ahead with this? Anything that we should change here. We are deploying our system on AWS, so if any AWS managed service can help here e.g. SNS+SQS combination?

Some statistics:

- ~1000 users, one group id per user
- 2-4 instances of microservice
- long polling every few seconds (~20s)
- average message size ~10KB

Comment: I don't understand. You're trying to use Kafka and ActiveMQ?

Comment: I updated the post a little bit. We are using Kafka. We thought that Integrating Kafka with ActiveMQ could solve our issue. We need thoughts on the same. We are also ready to shift to any other message broker.

Comment: I mean, Kafka is already persistent and distributed. I don't really under why you're trying to introduce something else. Kafka can handle thousands of consumer groups with little to no lag just fine

Comment: Yes, that is not the issue. Issue is we have 2 instances of a microservice which are reading from topic, it may be that 1 of them (MS2) may not be getting the message (depending on the partition where message is being produced). So if end client poll/GET request route to this MS2, it will wait for timeout or untill message is available in partition. So, end user will not get the message unless its request is routed to MS1 in this particular case. We know this is correct from Kafka behaviur but from end user, this is not desirable. It should get the message as soon as any message is available.

Comment: That sounds like a design problem, and expected behavior. You should funnel the data into a single source that the end-user queries consistently (e.g. a single database store), not dependent upon which instance the user is routed into from a load-balancer. For example, look at [Kafka Streams "Interactive Query" feature](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html#querying-remote-state-stores-for-the-entire-app)

Answer (score 0):

Broadly you have three possible approaches:

- You can dispense with using Kafka's consumer group functionality and allow each instance to consume from all partitions.
- You can make the instances of each service aware of each other.  For example, an instance which gets a request which can be fulfilled by another instance will forward the request there.  This is most effective if the messages can be partitioned by client on the producer end (so that a request from a given client only needs to be routed to an instance).  Even then, the consumer group functionality introduces some extra difficulty (rebalances mean that the consumer currently responsible for a given partition might not have seen all the messages in the partition).  You may want to implement your own variant of the consumer group coordination protocol, only on rebalance, the instance starts from some suitably early point regardless of where the previous consumer got to.
- If you can't reliably partition by client in the producer (e.g. the client is requesting a stream of all messages matching arbitrary criteria) then Kafka is really not going to be a fit and you probably want a database (with all the expense and complexity that implies).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. Some points: #1, each instance will get all messages causing duplication. #2, this is doable but cause lot of if and buts and potential issues. What about the solution of using any persistent mq along with kafka. So every instance of microsvc is reading its own partition and writing to single mq (separate mq for every end client). And client poll/get API is reading from that queue. You see any issue with this? This is kind of similar to sns faning out to sqs. Would having too much mq (~10k) cause the issue?

Comment: If you're going to write to a persistent MQ, why are you using Kafka?

Comment: Because there can be multiple different subscriber of the topic. Yes, we can Achieve same using e.g activemq with Topic, but again we have problem of two instances of same consumer/microsvc. With this model also, we need topic + queue combinations